# Solving in terms of polynomials for F,G such that Ff+Gg=c

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

I'm pretty new to mathematica and am trying to solve the following:

I have two explicit polynomials $f(x), g(x)$ with integer coefficients and a constant $c$ and I'm looking for two polynomials $F(x), G(x)$ such that 
$$F(x)f(x)+G(x)g(x)=c$$

I was hoping I could do this with `solve[...]` but no luck, it seems that will only give me roots of equations. I have a few systems like this I need to solve, so I've been trying to avoid explicit working out the coefficients and solving for them.

Comment: See [`PolynomialExtendedGCD`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolynomialExtendedGCD.html), esp. under "Applications."

Comment: Posting the explicit polynomials would help; it might also help to talk a bit more about what you've tried.